# Remote Server returns 404 not found error c#

Tags: c#, api, http-status-code-404

I am creating an application which checks to see the status of a user. I am getting a 404 not found error. Could anyone help code is posted below. What am i doing wrong?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Usernames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Hasan\Desktop\Usernames.txt");
        Parallel.ForEach(Usernames, Username =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient WebClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    WebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36");
                    string response = WebClient.DownloadString("https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=" + Username);
                    if(response.Contains("not - found"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Possibly Free : " + Username);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Error on Username : " + Username);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you browse the same url from browser?

Comment: @Hassan if your issue got solved...mark the answer & close this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the webapi returns an 404 error for each unkown user. At an 404 response the webclient throws an exception, so you need ro adapt your verification to something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Usernames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Hasan\Desktop\Usernames.txt");
    Parallel.ForEach(Usernames, Username =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient WebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                WebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36");
                string response = WebClient.DownloadString("https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=" + Username);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ( ex is WebException and (ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)?.StatusCode.ToString() ?? ex.Status.ToString() == "404" )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Possibly Free : " + Username);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("Error on Username : " + Username);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because for some reason your ***Username*** is blank &

your DownloadString becomes

> https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=

hence the 404 error..

Try To put a debugger on this line

```
string response = WebClient.DownloadString("https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=" + Username);
```

you will see a blank Username..

Because .. I checked the Api is otherwise working Fine for a valid username like

> https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=trump

and its returning a valid JSON

```
{"uniqueId":"hhus-04bce17a17b59979fbd97aa46110a650","name":"Trump","figureString":"hr-835-1402.hd-627-13.ch-3005-1326-97.lg-3483-1415-1415.he-3227-95.fa-3276-1328","motto":"covfefe","memberSince":"2011-05-11T22:20:28.000+0000","profileVisible":true,"selectedBadges":[{"badgeIndex":1,"code":"ACH_RegistrationDuration20","name":"100 % True Habbo XX","description":"Be a member of the community for 1825 days."},{"badgeIndex":2,"code":"UK824","name":"You took a quack at the duck games! (And won!)","description":""},{"badgeIndex":3,"code":"UK833","name":"Singapores National Flower","description":""},{"badgeIndex":4,"code":"UK835","name":"I picked a Lignum Vitae on Jamaica Day 2017!","description":""},{"badgeIndex":5,"code":"UK838","name":"Pretty Polly want a cracker?!","description":""}]}
```

Comment: Just checked it returns 404 for usernames which dont exist or are banned

Comment: ok my bad..I  rechecked and found **it returns 404 for usernames which dont exist or are banned** you are correct :)

Comment: Thanks mate, kind of annoying as I want to check which names are free to be registered

Comment: you can always check with any desired name...& if the name returns a 404 ...most probably it is available

Comment: accept this as answer...if this post helped you get the issue with your code :)